# Swipe to the same Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, swipe

I am trying to implement a left-right swipe gesture to navigate between an array of objects, that i can change the properties and take actions. The navigation is more of a previous-next approach. I have a table view that segues to this `Viewcontroller`, and i would like the user to check the next object without getting back to the `TableViewcontroller`. What is the best approach to implement this?
I know `PageController` isn't ideal in my situation as i'm not navigating between different VCs.

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: What kind of objects do you have? Details from tableview or images?

Comment: Both... Details from the tableview with more information and properties, including a collection view that contains images.

Comment: Check the screenshot i added @LauraCalinoiu

Comment: You could do it like the mail app does it with two arrow in the navigation bar (see http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/iOS-7-Mail-app-iOS-7-next-and-previous-mail.gif)

Answer (score 0):

A page view controller is the best way. Make the views view controllers instead. It does all the work for you.

Failing that you could use a collection view with a custom flow layout.

Failing that, you could roll your own custom view controller that implemented this feature.

### EDIT:

Based on your screenshot, where you say "swipe back and forth to move between rows of a table view" you need a collection view. Table views scroll **up and down** between rows. That's what they are made to do, and trying to implement a swipe interface to instead scroll side-to-side is crazy. Simply use a collection view configured for horizontal scrolling between cells.

Comment: Can you please explain the approach of the page view controller more? I've added a screenshot to the storyboard to my question @duncanc

Comment: I haven't used a page view controller in a while, but the docs are good, and I found it quite straightforward to use. A google search on "uipageviewcontroller scrolling swift example" yielded this: [**How to Use UIPageViewController in Swift**](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/)

Comment: Ok, what's with the down-vote? If somebody thinks my answer is low quality then by all means down-vote it, but please post a comment explaining what you think is wrong with it.

Comment: it wasn't me @duncan C